# Redirecting woocommerce cart page when user empties it

Tags: php, woocommerce

When a user is already in the cart page, and empties the cart, I want it to automatically redirect them back to another page.

I added this code to my functions.php file. When the user empties the cart, it does nothing until you refresh the page. Once you refresh, it actually redirects back to the url.

```
function empty_cart_redirection(){
    if ( is_page( 'cart' ) || is_cart() ) {
        
        if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( 'https://souzapc.com/store/' );
            exit();
        }
    }
    
}
```

My best guess is that the cart doesn't actually "update" to being zero until you refresh the page, but I am not familiar enough with woocommerce -or good enough of a coder- to know.

Only other thought is that removing the woocommerce empty cart message could be interfering.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );
```

Comment: Research "WooCommerce cart fragments." Might get you started.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My gut is emptying the cart does trigger an Ajax call that you can hook into....